# Pattern mining for item sets of length 2

Tags: data-mining, apriori

I am looking for association mining algorithm where I can mine frequent item sets of length 2 only. Is it better to use a query on database to compute frequent items when stopping at 2-itemsets.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a text file and you just want to find itemsets of length 2, you can just scan the file once and count the support of 2-itemsets direclty.  It will be very efficient.

For this case, you don't need to use Apriori FPGrowth, or any other fancy algorithm. You can just use a FOR loop over your file and a map to store the frequency of each pair of items that you encounter when scanning the file.

Then when the scan end, you will get all the support of two itemsets and you can output only those with a support  >= minsup.

Another way is to use a triangular matrix instead of a map to count the support of each pair of item. It would be a little bit faster than using a map but it may waste more memory if your data is sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Itemsets of length 2 don't benefit from pruning rules such as monotonicity.

You probably can compute the 2 itemsets using clever `JOIN`s with little cost in performance (and in fact, your DBMS will likely accelerate this better than your own code).

See [MadLIB](http://doc.madlib.net/latest/group__grp__assoc__rules.html) for a library to run Frequent Itemset Mining via SQL on PostgreSQL databases.

Comment: Is it valid for uncertain databases that have different transaction sizes?

Comment: Define "uncertain". It may well be "valid". The question that you should be asking yourself is: is it meaningful?

Comment: The transactions have different number of items.I need the frequent 2-itemsets that have the minimum support and minimum confidence. I do not have too much experience on this. I am not sure how this can be done using a database query. Could you give an example or any pointers where it has been used.

Comment: The queries of course depend a lot on how your data is organized (in particular, how you represent a transaction). So why don't you start, and update your question with what you've got?

Comment: I have a database table that stores transaction item mapping. Each transaction can have 1 to 100 items.
The table has following fields

mappingId( Primary Key)
itemId (int)
transactionId (int)

For running FP growth, I create an input file from the above table. Each line of the file contains list of items in a transaction.

Comment: The confidence is undefined for an itemset.  I think that you are looking for association rules. Association rules have a confidence.